# Bind custom data to a user?

Tags: java, jsf, seam

how can I bind custom data to a user?
Eg: User logs in > can only see Lists / Items he created himself.

Do I have to make an Entity User objekt, and further make it contain a @OneToMany list with these objects?
Or what is the best approach for things like this in general?

Tyvm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's common practise to have a User kind of entity if you have a system where a user can log in and has it's own stuff.

Consider a `Item` class:

```
@Entity
public class Item {

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;  // plus getter + setter

}
```

Then you get a list of items from a particular user:

```
String query = "SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE i.user = :user";
List<Item> items = entityManager.createQuery(query)
    .setParameter("user", user)  // where 'user' is the current user
    .getResultList;
```

And an example Bean in JSF:

```
public class ItemsBean implements Serializable {
    private User user;
    private List<Item> items;

    public User getUser() {
        if (user == null) {
            ExternalContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
            Principal principal = ctx.getUserPrincipal();
            user = ... // load user: username = principal.getName()
        }
        return user;
    }

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        if (items == null) {
            User user = getUser();
            List<Item> = ... // load items as shown above
        }
        return items;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really really helpful to get started. tyvm!! - One more question: when I persist an Item, the user within obvious has to be set already. How do I set the user? Or rather: how can I store the user when login took place? Do I just take a @Stateful UserManager, and retrieve this user when persisting an item?

Comment: @membersound You could store the User object in the HttpSession, or use a session scoped JSF bean. If you use the standard security mechanisms of the servlet API (login config in web.xml file) then you can get the username as shown in my code: `externalContext.getUserPrincipal().getName()`

Answer (score 0):

You can just add an 'author' attribute to each entity, and show only entities created by the current user:

```
  List<SomeEntity> entities = session.createCriteria(SomeEntity.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("author", currentUser)).list();
```